# Fixing MP4/M4A File Stucture

Tags: tags, mp4, m4a

I'm having an issue with tagging MP4/M4A files. The tagging operation goes A-OK. Well, I had an issue with the stco atom, but I fixed that. But now, when I play the MP4 file, mplayer gives me an error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x29db0a0] wrong sample count
```

However, the file does play.

Does anybody know what I'm missing? Here's what I do in order to add my tag atoms to the MP4 file. I have a feeling I'm not updating a certain atom just like the stco atom needed to be updated with the new absolute file position references.

1. Read in up to the 'moov' atom
2. Update 'moov's size to include the size of my tags (which are non-existent prior to the operation)
3. Write out all data (including updated 'moov' size) to the new file
4. Read in up to the 'stco' atom and the 4 bytes following (version and flag info that doesn't need to be changed).
5. Write out 'stco' header to the new file
6. Read in, process, and read out each 4-byte absolute file location to move them up by the size of the udta atom I'm going to be adding. Write each updated 4-byte location to the new file.
7. Write out the 'udta' atom (which directly follow 'stco') the new file.
8. Copy the remainder of the input file (the 'mdat' atom) to the new file.

Here's an AtomicParsley dump of the file structure:

```
Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 36, ends @ 36
Atom moov @ 36 of size: 61886, ends @ 61922
     Atom mvhd @ 44 of size: 108, ends @ 152
     Atom iods @ 152 of size: 33, ends @ 185
     Atom trak @ 185 of size: 32935, ends @ 33120
         Atom tkhd @ 193 of size: 92, ends @ 285
         Atom mdia @ 285 of size: 32835, ends @ 33120
             Atom mdhd @ 293 of size: 32, ends @ 325
             Atom hdlr @ 325 of size: 37, ends @ 362
             Atom minf @ 362 of size: 32758, ends @ 33120
                 Atom smhd @ 370 of size: 16, ends @ 386
                 Atom dinf @ 386 of size: 36, ends @ 422
                     Atom dref @ 394 of size: 28, ends @ 422
                 Atom stbl @ 422 of size: 32698, ends @ 33120
                     Atom stts @ 430 of size: 24, ends @ 454
                     Atom stsd @ 454 of size: 106, ends @ 560
                         Atom mp4a @ 470 of size: 90, ends @ 560
                             Atom esds @ 506 of size: 54, ends @ 560
                     Atom stsz @ 560 of size: 29548, ends @ 30108
                     Atom stsc @ 30108 of size: 40, ends @ 30148
                     Atom stco @ 30148 of size: 2972, ends @ 33120
     Atom udta @ 33120 of size: 28802, ends @ 61922
         Atom meta @ 33128 of size: 28794, ends @ 61922
             Atom hdlr @ 33140 of size: 34, ends @ 33174
             Atom ilst @ 33174 of size: 28748, ends @ 61922
                 Atom ©ART @ 33182 of size: 33, ends @ 33215
                     Atom data @ 33190 of size: 25, ends @ 33215
                 Atom ©nam @ 33215 of size: 77, ends @ 33292
                     Atom data @ 33223 of size: 69, ends @ 33292
                 Atom ©alb @ 33292 of size: 34, ends @ 33326
                     Atom data @ 33300 of size: 26, ends @ 33326
                 Atom covr @ 33326 of size: 28596, ends @ 61922
                     Atom data @ 33334 of size: 28588, ends @ 61922
Atom mdat @ 61922 of size: 2742564, ends @ 2804486
```

Comment: After seeing mention in FFmpeg code, I checked the stsz atom and the count in that atom is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dang, another stupid question I guess. I was yet another ID-ten-T programming error. When I processed the 'stco' atom I only read in 12 bytes (size, atom name, version, flags) and forgot to read in the 'total entries' 4-byte section. So, what happened was I ended up adding the size of the 'udta' atom to the 'total entries' block, which caused the FFmpeg error. I was able to figure this out by looking at the FFmpeg source and the double-checking the structure of 'stco'.